# Fill new column using only part of the content in another column

Tags: r

I have a column called "ID" in my dataframe which consist of sample names such as: C1, C2, C3,...C20,O1,..., O20.

Now I would like to create a new column called "treatment" where I fill the word "Conventional" for all the cases where there was a "C" in front of the number in "ID" and  "Organic" where there was an "O" before the name.

Example

```
ID      treatment
C1      conventional
C2      conventional
O1      organic
```

I found a similar question here but there they used the whole content and not just part of the content as I would need: [Aggregate data in one column based on values in another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7560671/aggregate-data-in-one-column-based-on-values-in-another-column)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the tidyverse nomenclature too, there's some very powerful easy-to-follow commands in there and you don't fall foul of the if_else issues where you can easily get lost;

```
ID <- c('C1', 'C2', 'O1', 'CG18', 'OG20')
dat <- data.frame(ID)

require(tidyverse)

# use 'case_when' from dplyr and 'stringr' commands
dat <- dat %>% 
  mutate(
    treatment = case_when(

      # regex anchors 'C' at beginning followed by digits
      str_detect(ID, '^C\\d+') ~ 'conventional'  

      # regex anchors 'O' at beginning followed by digits
      , str_detect(ID, '^O\\d+') ~ 'organic'

      # regex to detect 'G'
      , str_detect(ID, 'G') ~ 'grassland'
      , TRUE ~ 'NA')
  )
```

[image: should give you this]

Comment: better use `NA_character_` than `'NA'`

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much "sorearm"

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper: why is it better and how do I write the code then, resp. where do I add this function?

Comment: @Ch_soil  I think Moody_Mudskipper is referring to the TRUE ~ 'NA' part of my script, just use TRUE ~ 'NA_character_'  ?

Comment: no, don't use simple quotes, just `TRUE ~ NA_character_` :)

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
mydf$treatment=ifelse(substr(mydf$ID,1,1)=="C","Conventional","Organic")
```

?

Comment: Thank you so much!! This worked!

Actually, I have two additional ID's: e.g. CG18 and OG20 but as as soon as there is a "G" I would like to name it "Grassland" in the treatment. So that in the end I have "Conventional", "Organic" and "Grassland". Do you know how I could manage this?

Comment: You would add a nested ifelse to check also for G, or you could run a second command checking only for G.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do it this way :

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c("C1","C2","O1"))
lkp <- c(C = 'conventional', O = 'organic')
# or to answer your comment on other answer :
# lkp <- c(C = 'conventional', O = 'organic', CG = 'grassland', OG = 'grassland')
df$treatment <- lkp[gsub("\\d.*","",df$ID)]
df
#   ID    treatment
# 1 C1 conventional
# 2 C2 conventional
# 3 O1      organic
```

Comment: I am not sure whether it is ok to ask a follow up question here but it's for the same data as above. Now I would like to add a additional column and fill with "AM" for all the rows where the TIME was earlier than 14.04 and with "PM" when it was later than 14.04. I tried the following code:
df.HMR$time=ifelse(df.HMR$TIME <14:04:00.000,"AM","PM").
I think I get error messages 1) because TIME is saves as a "chr" and not a number thus the "<" sign wouldn't work? and 2) the < would only work for 14 but not the whole command (because I have ":" between hours and minutes. Can someone help me?

Comment: you should learn about working with dates and times in R, it will be very rewarding I promise, I recommend you lookup some tutorial on package `lubridate` as it makes things really intuitive.

Comment: This is very helpful and I didn't know. Thanks @Moody_Mudskipper